# test with regex that is make of variables

Tags: javascript

This javascript code is expected to filter an array to return only items which has 2 strings in them, the strings are in variables, but it is filtering out all matches which are expected to be returned. Any idea how to fix it so that it returns the items which include the texts in the variables? Thanks

```js
let var1 = '234A'
let var2 = '1.4'

// examples of items
let myArr = ['it has 234AB but with 1.4 factors', 'it is 234 and 1.5'];

// need to return 'it has 234 but with 1.4 factors'
return myArr.filter(y => new RegExp('/' + var1 + '.*?' + var2.replace('.','\.') + '/', 'i').test(y))
```

Comment: Your regexp tries to match a `/` first (`new RegExp('/' + ...)`). None of your strings match because none of them contain `/`.

Comment: `replace('.','\.')` is a no-op. `'\.'` is the same string as `'.'`.

Comment: Why are you using `i`? Your regexp doesn't match any letters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a regex with the `RegExp` constructor you should not add the `/` in the string. Those are only used in regex *literals*, not in strings.

The replacement of `'.'` with `'\.'` does not help, as the backslash is interpreted by the string literal and not visible to the RegExp constructor. You should double the backslash. That way the string will have one literal backslash, which will be visible to the RegExp constructor.

But there is also another limitation. As you have it now, the occurrences must be in that order, so it would not detect the items when occurring in reversed order.

Why not just use `includes` and `&&`?

```
myArr.filter(y => y.includes(var1) && y.includes(var2))
```

Comment: the reason why I used regex is to take advantage of the case insensitive which is needed when the strings values changes.

Comment: Sure, but if that is your only reason for regular expressions, you'll have better performance if you just convert the involved strings to lower case before doing the match.